# How do I find the number of objects that are alive in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to find the objects of a class that are currently alive in C++.
Please tell me a solution for this.
Also, please correct if my logic is wrong!

- Declare a global variable.
- Increment it during the constructor invocation.
- Decrement during destructor invocation.

Thanks in advance.

Sanjeev

Comment: Why do you need to find the number of objects of a certain type? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Just this! Finding the number of objects that are alive currently!

Comment: No, what I meant was what is the underlying reason why you need to count objects? There are very few use cases for counting objects, and unless you're just experimenting around, half the time I can come up with a better solution to your actual problem. You need to describe the goal.

Answer (score 6):

keep a static variable in your class as count. Global variables are not good practice.

Answer (score 6):

Your logic is correct except for one thing: don't make it a global variable; it is untidy and there is the danger that a bug in some other code might modify it. Instead make it a private static member variable of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the curiously recurring template pattern, it is great for this sort of thing and the example in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) shows how to use it for an object counter.

```
template <typename T>
struct counter
{
    counter()
    {
        ++objects_created;
        ++objects_alive;
    }

    virtual ~counter()
    {
        --objects_alive;
    }
    // if you are using multiple threads, these need to be protected
    // with interlocked operations as appropriate per your compiler + platform
    static int objects_created;
    static int objects_alive;
};
template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_created( 0 );
template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_alive( 0 );

class X : counter<X>
{
    // ...
};

class Y : counter<Y>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Edited to format code properly. This is missing a copy constructor, though, and I'm not sure whether the destructor should be virtual - perhaps making it protected would be a better idea (perhaps the constructors should also be protected, to avoid increasing the count by creating counters!).

Comment: thanks, we should probably ping wiki too on this since I copied the example from there.

In my own uses of this pattern the classes are usually non-copyable.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in C++. Tracking constructor and destructor does not guarantee the accuracy: how do you prevent a memory copy like this:

```
memcpy(buf, &instance, sizeof(T));
T* anotherInstance = (T*)buf;
```

Comment: He may not being doing any of those crazy memcpy shenanigans in his program, so he wouldn't have to worry.

Comment: By this logic, you can't rely on any code to work properly, because someone could always go and write random garbage over your objects using memcpy.

Comment: @PigBen: That's the point, it's simply impossible in language like C++ in which memory can be directory manipulated. May be the original question can be rephrased to how to track constructor and destructor usage.

Comment: @Codism:  No, by your logic, even that is impossible.  Because whatever variable you are using to keep track of calls to the constructor could be overwritten by poking around in memory.

Comment: @PigBen: I don't think it's a fair argument because poking around in memory is a bug while in C/C++, using a buffer declared in another type (usually char*) is quite common.

Comment: @Codism: You mean in C.  Not in C++.  I've certainly never written C++ code like that.

Comment: @Codism: Let me clarify that.  I've never used memcpy to copy class objects.  If I did, it was for a brief intellectual curiosity.  But never in production code.  I used to use memcpy for copying long arrays of integers or other simple types like that, especially for copying bitmap data(not the whole object, just the pixel data).  But I would never try to copy a class object like that.